# iphone - Objective-C "message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I try to get all subviews using this method but when i run the application, i have a  message sent to deallocated instance error.

```
subviewsArray = self.view.subviews;
for (int i=0; i <subviewsArray.count; i++) {
    UIView *subview = [subviewsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (subview.tag >= 0) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

And in my .h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *subviewsArray;
```

Comment: @Pfitz have you heard of properties?

Comment: @guitarflow NSArray has no property count ...

Comment: @Pfitz, sorry, thought the dot operator was for properties only. My bad.

Comment: @JamesWebster ok ok its working this way too - still don't like it :)

Comment: @MrA59 everything looks fine in this code, may be you are releasing the subviewsArray in dealloc method, which is not retained.

Comment: @chad I try the method mentioned by George
 for(UIView *temp in self.view.subviews )
{
    [temp removeFromSuperview];
}

And i still have the problem :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your loop code to  this :

```
for (int i=subviewsArray.count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    UIView *subview = [subviewsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (subview.tag >= 0) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

The Reason you are getting this issue is because, as your loop goes ahead from 0 to say 10th(assuming last) view, you start removing them from parent view, and so the count also changes and so the indexes of the remaining views.

In the end you end up trying to remove a view and send it a message *removeFromSuperview*, which is already deallocated, all because of change in the index.
better go reverse, last index to first.

I am surprised, why you didn't get index out of bound exception.

not just here, in general whenever you traverse through a collection based on index and try removing elements, you will always face this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Change your loop code to look like this:

```
subviewsArray = self.view.subviews;
for (int i=0; i <subviewsArray.count - 1; i++) {
    UIView *subview = [subviewsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (subview.tag >= 0) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(UIView *temp in self.view.subviews )
{
    [temp removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Or this:

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I try your method, but i still have the problem. [MyViewControllerExample view]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7268870

Comment: Then your best chance is with the Zombies Instruments. Make sure you run your app on the simulator because this instrument is not available on the device. Make the steps up to the crash and see what the instrument is telling you. Maybe with more information we can find a solution.

Comment: I can't use the simulator because i need to connect a sensor cardio to make test using the iphone ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: Then place your code in a @try-catch statement and print out the exception description. Also , this might be a little too hardcore , but I found useful at times to print out the memory adresses and see which object is giving me a hard time.

Comment: I tried this : 
@try{
        subviewsArray = self.view.subviews;
    }@catch (NSException * e) {
         NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }

The error are in the subviewsArray line ! it blocks at this line and it don't show the exception !

Comment: `subviewsArray = self.view.subviews;` There simply cannot be something wrong with this code. No need to place it into a try-catch block just by itself. Add in the try-catch block the for loop with the removeFromSuperView call.

Comment: I tried this  `@try{
        for(UIView *temp in self.view.subviews )
        {
        
            if (temp.tag >= 0) {
                [temp removeFromSuperview];
            }   
        }
    }@catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    }`

And i got the same error at the "for" line

Comment: @MrA59: It seems that your viewControllers view is getting released.

Answer (score 1):

```
 self.subviewsArray = self.view.subviews;
for (int i=0; i <self.subviewsArray.count - 1; i++) {
    UIView *subview = [self.subviewsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if (subview.tag >= 0) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: `<self.subviewsArray.count - 1` that would just skip the last view.

Answer (score 1):

First though maybe ARC was causing it, but maybe simplifying the for loop would fix this

```
for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
{

}
```